# Explanation of Offset algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, cnc

I have a small problem. I am trying to build my own cnc and implement offset algorithm, but i am not able to understand what "TIP", "FIP" mean. This seems so complicated!
This is the link to description this algorithm:
Here's [a link](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00518005/document) 
I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: So you can explain me  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions reads: *If the intersection point obtained by extended intersecting is on the line segment/arc, then the point is called a true intersection point (TIP). Otherwise, it is called a false intersection point (FIP).*

My interpretation is that a TIP is a point on a segment (line or arc) that intersects with another segment or an extension of it. A FIP is an intersection of two extended segments that does not lie on any of them.

I agree with you, the definition is not clear (which is not good for a definition). Another interpretation (coming from the names rather than from the wording) would be that a TIP is the intersection of two segments and a FIP is the projected intersection of their extensions. My recommendation is to bear both interpretations in mind and keep reading until the definitions become clearer from their actual use.